# got "dumpvar.pl not available" message when debugging a perl script

Tags: perl, debugging

I got the following error message when debugging a perl script.

> "dumpvar.pl not available"

I can enter into debug mode, but when I use the x command to check a variable's value, the error message show up, what's wrong?

my perl version as below

> This is perl, v5.8.8 built for sun4-solaris

my OS info as below

> SunOS 5.10 Generic_118822-30 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440

Comment: The file is part of the Perl distribution.. I just checked, and it came with Perl 5.8.8

Comment: What do you get from `perl -e'do "dumpvar.pl" or die $@; print "ok\n"'`?

Comment: it prints "ok" now, but i am sure it's not before I reset the $PERL5LIB environment variable, Joe's method works well, thank you all the same ikegami!

Comment: Actually, I was getting to the same place. :) For future reference, when asked to do a test, do it in the same environment in which you are encountering the problem!

Comment: it prints "ok" in the same environment

Comment: If that was true, you wouldn't need to change PERL5LIB?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you dropped the equivalent of /usr/lib/perl/perl-5.16.0/lib/5.16.0 from @INC? If that's not there, then the debugger can't run it to get the 'x' output.

Let's check your Perl install:

```
perl -de0
x [qw(a b c)]
```

If that works, you've bollixed up your @INC somehow in the program you're trying to debug. In the same debugger session:

```
p $INC['dumpvar.pl']
```

will print out the directory dumpvar.pl lives in, and you can check @INC in the program you're trying to debug to see if the @INC entry for that library has been dropped.

If the 'x' command above doesn't work, and you get something like

```
Can't locate dumpvar.pl in @INC (@INC contains: ...
```

then you have a broken Perl and need to either install it yourself ([perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) is very handy for this) or talk to your system administrator about it.

Comment: Thank you very much Joe, this is really helpful! is was caused by a wrong perl lib path(we have a customer version of perl and I export the $PERL5LIB variable to point to that path, but dumpvar.pl was not there.), you method works! thanks!